# interpreting a token return in PHP using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm having trouble interpreting the response I get from this server.  When the user tries to access a page on my server, this PHP runs first to see if they have a valid token (through the previous login page that I'm not displaying here...):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$searchURL = "http://example.com/isTokenValid?";               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $searchURL);
$answerSearch = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I type in `http://example.com/isTokenValid?"` into Chrome, I get one of two responses:

```
boolean=true

boolean=false
```

I've tried using php to interpret `$answerSearch`, using `print_r` and `var_dump` to see what `$answerSearch` contains, but I must be doing something wrong because `$answerSearch` is always true.

`print_r($answerSearch) // 1`

`var_dump($answerSearch) // bool(true)`

I'm doing something wrong in my cURL code, but I'm not sure what...

Comment: have curl send over a chrome useragent, and see if the response changser. remember that the server can send back ANYTHING it wants, and tailor its response to match whatever the requesting user is. e.g a scraper, a browser, a security-paranoiac using the "telnet to port 80" browser.

Comment: is curl even the proper way to go about this?  In the past I've used cURL for much more complex things - here I just want to see if a URL tells me "true" or "false".  The login is already done...

Comment: curl is just a tool. it's up to you if you want to use a swiss army knife, or a plain kitchen knife. either way, you can cut stuff.

Comment: I sent over a different useragent and it's still giving me the same thing.  I don't know how to interpret the response into something PHP can understand... the response, `boolean=true` or `boolean=false` is what's hanging me up.

Comment: it's probably chrome doing interpretation itself, then. since print_r=1 and var_dump=true, then maybe chrome is trying to be friendly and doing essentially what var_dump is doing - taking a boolean value and displaying it "nicely". if you control the script producing this stuff, have it output something else as a test, e.g. `0`, or `false`, or wahtever.